# as3 Number type - Logic issues with large numbers

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm curious about an issue spotted in our team with a very large number:

```
var n:Number = 64336512942563914;
trace(n < Number.MAX_VALUE); // true
trace(n); // 64336512942563910

var a1:Number = n +4;
var a2:Number = a1 - n;
trace(a2); // 8  Expect to see 4
trace(n + 4 - n); // 8

var a3:Number = parseInt("64336512942563914");
trace(a3); // 64336512942563920

n++;
trace(n); //64336512942563910
trace(64336512942563914 == 64336512942563910); // true
```

What's going on here?

Although `n` is large, it's smaller than `Number.MAX_VALUE`, so why am I seeing such odd behaviour?

I thought that perhaps it was an issue with formatting large numbers when being `trace`'d out, but that doesn't explain `n + 4 - n == 8`

Is this some weird floating point number issue?

Comment: I was having some hard time trying to return some 64 bit integers from a java service to as3 client. Thanks to your post I now figured out what it is. Just another example of how crappy AS3 actually is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a floating point issue, but it is not a weird one. It is all expected behavior.

Number data type in AS3 is actually a "64-bit double-precision format as specified by the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE-754)" ([source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9c.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f7f)). Because the number you assigned to *n* has too many digits to fit into thos 64 bits, it gets rounded off, and that's the reason for all the "weird" results.

If you need to do some exact big integer arithmetic, you will have to use a custom big integer class, e.g. [this one](http://kingtut666.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/bigint-in-actionscript-3-0/).

Answer (score 1):

Numbers in flash are double precision floating point numbers. Meaning they store a number of significant digits and and exponent. It favors a larger range of expressible numbers over the precision of the numbers due to memory constraints. At some point, numbers with a lot of significant digits, rounding will occur. Which is what you are seeing; the least significant digits are being rounded. Google double precision floating point numbers and you'll find a bunch of technical information on why.

It is the nature of the datatype. If you need precise numbers you should really stick to uint or int based integers. Other languages have fixed point or bigint number processing libraries (sometimes called BigInt or Decimal) which are wrappers around ints and longs to express much larger numbers at the cost of memory consumption.

Answer (score 1):

We have an as3 implementation of BigDecimal copied from Java that we use for ALL calculations. In a trading app the floating point errors were not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

To be safe with integer math when using Numbers, I checked the [AS3 documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html) for Number and it states:

> The Number class can be used to represent integer values well beyond
>   the valid range of the int and uint data types. The Number data type
>   can use up to 53 bits to represent integer values, compared to the 32
>   bits available to int and uint.

A 53 bit integer gets you to 2^53 - 1, if I'm not mistaken which is 9007199254740991, or about 9 quadrillion.  The other 11 bits that help make up the 64 bit Number are used in the exponent.  The number used in the question is about 64.3 quadrillion.   Going past that point (9 quadrillion) requires more bits for the significant number portion (the mantissa) than is allotted and so rounding occurs.  A helpful [video](https://youtu.be/pQs_wx8eoQ8) explaining why this makes sense (by PBS Studio's Infinite Series).

So yeah, one must search for outside resources such as the BigInt.  Hopefully, the resources I linked to are useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

This is, indeed, a floating point number approximation issue.

I guess n is to large compared to 4, so it has to stick with children of its age:
`trace(n - n + 4)` is ok since it does n-n = 0; 0 + 4 = 4;

Actually, `Number` is not the type to be used for large integers, but floating point numbers. If you want to compute large integers you have to stay within the limit of `uint.MAX_VALUE`.

Cheers!